# Universal Link not working despite AASA is set correctly - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links

I have been working to implement universal links for my app, but have encountered difficulty. Despite having a valid AASA file and properly configuring my associated domains, I am unable to troubleshoot the issue and am unsure if it is a problem with my setup or a bug on Apple's end.

- AASA VALID And hosted :

[image: AASA VALID]

[image]

- Associated domain set :

[image]

- The Only thing that i don't get when i try to troubleshoot it with console i get:

[image]

I would appreciate any insight or experience that you may have had with a similar issue.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I see one clear issue here.

The associated domain is set incorrectly, it should not contain 'https://'

It should be set as:

'applinks:c870-2a02-3032-10-edbc-8dcf-b81f-d084-83e1.eu.ngrok.io'

Try this and see if it works.
If it helps, please consider marking this as the answer.
If not, please let me know what issue you see after making the above change.